# Would there be tax due on an inheritance received from a U.S. citizen that lived in the U.K.?

Tags: united-states, taxes, united-kingdom, real-estate, inheritance

My mother passed away in August.  She was a US citizen living in UK for 40+ years.  Do my brother and I have to pay tax to bring the cash into the US?  No tax had to be paid in UK.  Not a big inheritance.  Total cash is about $60K each.

There was also a house.  Half the house has been in a trust which my brother and I took ownership of when my stepfather passed.  My mother's half has now passed to us.  When we do sell the house, probably 2 years, do we have to pay US tax on that money?

Comment: Is it safe to assume the value of the house is less than $4 million?

Comment: Is the house in the UK or the US?